# Как реализовать кастомный выпадающий список?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, dropdown

Имеются проблемы, список выходит за пределы блока и ширина `dropdown` разная.

И они все 3 должны быть одинакового размера в ширину, тоесть не должна прыгать ширина списка

А можно еще как то без js обойтись?

```js
$('.dropdown__header').on('click', function() {
  let dropdown = $(this).parents('.dropdown');
  dropdown.toggleClass('open');
});
$('.dropdown__body > div').on('click', function() {
  let dropdown = $(this).parents('.dropdown');
  let name = $(this).data('name');
  let text = $(this).text();
  dropdown.children('.dropdown__header').data('value', name);
  dropdown.children('.dropdown__header').text(text);
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown__header {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.25em 1.25em 0.25em 0.5em;
}
.dropdown__header:after {
  content: "▼";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 0.575rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
.dropdown__body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -1px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #3f3f3f;
  border-radius: 2px;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  transition: all 0.15s linear;
  visibility: hidden;
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown.open .dropdown__body {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 100%;
}
.dropdown__body > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.05em 0.5em;
}
.dropdown__body > div:hover {
  background: #afafaf;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__header" data-value="all">All</div>
  <div class="dropdown__body">
    <div data-name="all">All</div>
    <div data-name="prices">Prices</div>
    <div data-name="views">Views</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__header" data-value="prices">Prices</div>
  <div class="dropdown__body">
    <div data-name="all">All</div>
    <div data-name="prices">Prices</div>
    <div data-name="views">Views</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="dropdown__header" data-value="views">Views</div>
  <div class="dropdown__body">
    <div data-name="all">All</div>
    <div data-name="prices">Prices</div>
    <div data-name="views">Views</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А какой ширины должен быть выпадающий список, если в нём один из пунктов, длиной "фффффффффффффффффф"?

Answer (score 0):

Тебе надо задать какую-то фиксированную ширину, чтобы все списки были одинаковой ширины.
Также тебе не надо указывать height:100%, так как высота наследуется от родителя, у которого высота как у dropdown__header.

Все, что тебе нужно добавить это:

```
.dropdown .dropdown__body {
    width: 100px;
    height: auto;
}
```